# How can I change a project in a solution from application to static library?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

Background: In visual studio 2015, I have an project `A` built as an application. I want to create two packages `B` and `C` which wrap the contents of `A` into a DLL (in `B`) and into a runable application in `C`. After removing the `main` from `A`, I want to change project `A` from an application to a static library.
I tried changing the

`Project Properties|Configuration Properties|General|Project Defaults`

from `Application (.exe)` to `Static Library (.lib)`. This leads to a linker error:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1561: entry point must be defined
```

Obviously, Visual Studio still thinks that this subproject has to be compiled like an application (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ky737ya4.aspx) ). It therefore expects that there is a `int main()` which I don't want to have anymore.

So, **how can I change the project type so that it is compiled as a static library?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems to be no way to change the build type from the GUI.
However, this can be done by altering the file `A.vcxproj`.

Search for all tags `<ConfigurationType>` and change them from `Application` (or whatever you have there) to `StaticLibrary`.
This only needs to be done for project `A` - the solution will adapt, the next time you start it in Visual Studio.

To properly link `A` into `B` and `C`, don't forget to:

1) Add a reference from `B` and `C` to `A`.

Open `Solution>Project B/C>References`, choose `Add Reference`, add reference to `A`.

2) Add a project dependency from `B` and `C` to `A`.

Open the context menu for any project and select `Build Dependencies...>Project Dependencies>Dependencies`. Add `A` as a dependency for both `B` and `C`.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2022, you can change the *Configuration Type* in *Project Properties*:

- *Project Properties* > *General* > *Configuration Type*

The choices I see are *Makefile*, *Application (.exe)*, *Dynamic Library (.dll)*, *Static library (.lib)* and *Utility*.

My project was imported as a Dynamic Lib.  I updated this setting and it now generates Static Lib.  Related to the other answer, changing this setting in Visual Studio did result in the `<ConfigurationType>` value within the `Project.vcxproj` file to be updated.  I figure doing it through Visual Studio instead of directly in the file would be safer.